# Canvas game not working as excepted at low FPS

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw, frame-rate, timedelta

I'm trying to create a canvas game for fun and learning but my code not running as I want.

I have a character in the game that walks right/left/up/down and every move adds some px to image and making the animation. 
It means if the character is on 20px, 40px of the screen and you move right, it will be 40px, 40px.

My code goes like that:

```
start() {
    this.deltaTime();
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.gameWindow.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.map.drawMap();
    this.player.drawPlayer();
    this.text.drawText('Coordinates X:'+this.player.position.x+', Y:'+this.player.position.y, 5, 5);
    this.text.drawText('FPS: '+this.graphic.lastfps, 5, 17);
    this.text.drawText('ms: '+this.graphic.lastDelta, 5, 29);
    this.text.drawText('delta: '+this.graphic.delta, 5, 41);
    this.text.drawText('Running time: '+this.runningTime, 5, 53);
    this.text.drawTextList();
}
deltaTime() {
    // Calc FPS
    let fps, delta;
    let performanceUse = performance.now();
    fps = delta = Math.floor(performanceUse / 1000);
    if(this.graphic.lastTimeFPSDate !== fps) {
        this.graphic.lastTimeFPSDate = fps;
        this.graphic.lastfps = this.graphic.fps;
        this.graphic.fps = 1;
        this.runningTime++;
    }
    else
        this.graphic.fps++;
    // Calc Delta
    this.graphic.delta = performanceUse - this.graphic.lastTimeDeltaCall;
    this.graphic.lastTimeDeltaCall = performanceUse;
    if(this.graphic.lastTimeDeltaDate !== delta) {
        this.graphic.lastTimeDeltaDate = delta;
        this.graphic.lastDelta = Math.floor(this.graphic.delta);
    }
}
animationMove(to) {
    let target;                                                                                             
    let animationSpeed = (this.running) ? this.engine.gameSpeed.runSpeed : this.engine.gameSpeed.walkSpeed; 
    let distanceBettwenSquares = this.engine.mapSettings.pxPerSquare;                                       
    let seconds = 1000;                                                                                   
    let everyStepAnimation = Math.ceil((60 / this.engine.graphic.lastfps));                               
    let runLoopForAnimationEveryXMS = Math.floor(seconds / distanceBettwenSquares);                     
    let stopLoop = false;
    let sign = null;
    //console.clear();
    console.log('runLoopForAnimationEveryXMS: '+runLoopForAnimationEveryXMS+', everyStepAnimation: '+everyStepAnimation);
    console.log('FPS: '+this.engine.graphic.lastfps+', deltaTime: '+this.engine.graphic.lastDelta);
    console.log('REAL FPS: '+this.engine.graphic.fps+', REAL deltaTime: '+this.engine.graphic.delta);
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    this.engine.animationLoop(true, 0, runLoopForAnimationEveryXMS, (id) => {
        // Stop the animation if it is 0 or bigger than the distance that require or stopLoop is true (which mean the numbers get over fed)
        if (this.playerAnimation[target] === 0 || Math.abs(this.playerAnimation[target]) > distanceBettwenSquares || stopLoop) {
            this.engine.animationLoop.kill(id);
            this.playerAnimation.walk = false;
            this.playerAnimation.needAnimation = true;
            this.playerAnimation[target] = 0;
            return;
        }
        // Do each step of the animation
        sign = Math.sign(this.playerAnimation[target]);                                                        
        this.playerAnimation[target] = sign * (Math.abs(this.playerAnimation[target]) - everyStepAnimation);  
        if (Math.sign(this.playerAnimation[target]) !== sign)                                                  
            stopLoop = true;                                                                                
    });
}
function game() {
    start();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(game);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(game);
```

When pressing on a key, it does the animation first (moving the image a few px each step) and then updating the variables for the current position.

Here is the problem:
Sometimes the animation goes slow, even "jumping".
With no real FPS changes (1-2 +-).

So my questions are:

1. First, did I do right the calculation of FPS and delta? (I didn't wrong?)
2. As you can see, I used in main to draw the details and in setInterval for change the details (so the changes are never going to slow the code), that how it should be done?
3. In my code, I suppose that 60FPS is the best and based on that for each step,
   I don't want to suppose that because maybe in the future the FPS be even higher,
   so how should I do the calculation for one move (square which is 20 px) will take one second?
4. Sometimes the code runs slowly and sometimes faster, why is that?
5. How should I use in the delta time here?
6. At the first second of the game, everything is on maximal speed because the FPS is still zero. How can I fix this?

Thanks and sorry for my English, even answering one answer will help!

Comment: I'd suggest either 1. use the delta time to calculate the distance, or 2. fixed distance per frame.

Comment: and please post [mcve], it helps to understand the real problem.

Comment: Don't forget to 'round' your numbers for pixels and the like if the delta time calc returns large decimal point numbers

Comment: If you are animating, you should be using `requestAnimationFrame` to loop and a delta time to calculate all changes. Base all movements on px/second (or some other measure of distance) and rotations on deg/second with velocity vectors and use acceleration vectors to adjust these values. It is more complicated to start with but once you have the objects set up it will make things much easier.

Comment: @appleapple I edited my post and make it more understandable. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @James Coyle can you review my post, as you can see I'm using requestAnimationFrame but how delta time come with that? Thanks for helping!